# Need to take screenshot without Imagebuttons

Tags: android

I am trying to take screenshot of my app screen programatically. The Layout file has some ImageButtons and a Textview field. When the capture screen happens, the resulted image contains the buttons too. Is there a way to take screenshot without the imagebuttons?

Below are the code snippet and layout files

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xyz.abc.def.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/buttons_layout"
        android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:shadowColor="#edeff2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="25"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

button_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/refresh"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/shareButton"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/share"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code to take screenshot

```
private void captureScreen() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +now+".jpg";

        View view = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imagePath = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            sendScreen(filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);

        }

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: `button.setVisibility(View.GONE)` just before the screenshot? And show them back when you're done

Comment: Just like @MichałK suggested, hide the buttons before screenshot and show the buttons after screenshot. But i suggest `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` as `View.INVISIBLE` will not distort the other views that might be dependant on the button

Comment: Thanks Michal and Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the image button invisible just before taking the screenshot and then make it visible.

```
private void captureScreen() {
    //make unwanted views invisible
    findViewById(R.id.refreshButton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.shareButton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +now+".jpg";

    View view = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    File imagePath = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        sendScreen(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);

    }
    //make those views visible again
    findViewById(R.id.refreshButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.shareButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Any time @AshishBanerjee :)

Answer (score 3):

If it is just the text view you want as I can see it is full screen.
Try using

```
    View view = findViewById(R.id.text1); // instead of R.id.activity_main
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Basically point is keep those views in separate container whose screen shot you want and then get the drawable of that particular container.

Comment: Thanks Ishan, tried this but ran into an issue. Actually the relative layout has a background. When I get the text1 instead of activity_main, the screenshot comes with Text but with a black background.

Comment: add background to text view as it is full screen and keep it as first child in XML, I mean write it before include.